# input iterator + output iterator + X = forward iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I want to solve the equation in the title and find X. As far as I understand, an input or output iterator, unlike a forward iterator, gets invalidated as soon as a copy of it is advanced. Is there any additional requirement in order for a type T which satisfies both input iterator concept and output iterator concept to satisfy the forward iterator concept?

In any case, can you provide a real-world example of an iterator which is both input and output but is not forward? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Iterator categories deal with operations allowed on an iterator. Dereferencing forward iterator must yield `T&` (C++03) while dereferencing input iterator must only yield a type convertible to `T`. As an example, `vector<bool>::iterator` is an input/output iterator, but not a forward iterator (because dereferencing it returns a proxy convertible to `bool` — because you can't return a reference to a bit).

Comment: Exactly what I was asking. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

And according to the chart [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/) a forward iterator can be default constructed, but a input or output iterator can not.